# Django REST framework getstream notifications

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, getstream-io

I'm trying to follow the getstream docs for django with rest framework. https://github.com/GetStream/stream-django

Here is a minimal drf api cloned from the drf tutorial https://github.com/morenoh149/django-rest-framework-getstream

I get an error

```
TypeError at /notifications/
Object of type Feed is not JSON serializable
```

when opening `/notifications/` in a browser. How do I write an endpoint to show the user's notifications?

views.py

> ```
> class NotificationViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
> """
> This viewset returns a notifications feed for the logged in user.
> The feed contains events for when a relevant snippet is created.
> """
> serializer_class = NotificationSerializer
>
> def list(self, request):
>     user_id = request.user.id
>     notification_feed = feed_manager.get_notification_feed(user_id)
>     return Response(notification_feed)
> ```

serializers.py

```
class ActivitySerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    id = serializers.UUIDField()
    foreign_id = serializers.CharField()
    verb = serializers.CharField()
    time = serializers.DateTimeField()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        object_serializer = kwargs.pop("object_serializer", None)
        actor_serializer = kwargs.pop("actor_serializer", None)
        super().__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        if object_serializer:
            self.fields["object"] = object_serializer()
        else:
            self.fields["object"] = serializers.CharField()
        if actor_serializer:
            self.fields["actor"] = actor_serializer()
        else:
            self.fields["actor"] = serializers.CharField()


class AggregatedSerializer(ActivitySerializer):
    group = serializers.CharField()
    activities = ActivitySerializer(many=True)


class NotificationSerializer(AggregatedSerializer):
    is_seen = serializers.BooleanField()
    is_read = serializers.BooleanField()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks JPG, you're correct. With a few more steps you can even get 'enriched' activities. Harry Moreno, check the example I provided on github:

https://github.com/pterk/django_twitter/blob/master/stream_twitter/views.py#L141 copied here for your convenience:

```
class TimelineAPIView(APIView):
    """
    Timeline as an api view, enriched with local data
    """
    def get(self, request):
        feeds = feed_manager.get_news_feeds(self.request.user.id)
        activities = feeds.get('timeline').get()['results']
        enriched_activities = enricher.enrich_activities(activities)
        serializer = get_activity_serializer(enriched_activities, TweetSerializer, None, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: I cannot adapt your proof of concept into a notifications feed. Could you try getting my repo to work minimally to power a notifications feed?

Comment: A couple of things: you mixed news feeds and notification feeds, the object serializer needed context for the HyperLinkedIdentityFields, loading fixtures doesn't trigger a sync with stream (see the raw parameter) and last but not least my proof of concept didn't work for aggregated / notification feeds. I've forked your project and pushed a commit that adds a notification when you add a snippet via the admin.

See here: https://github.com/GetStream/django-rest-framework-getstream

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about the code snippet inside the **`list()`** method. But, I think you are returning the **`Feed`** model instance to the **`Response`** class, but DRF expects some data of JSON type.

So, return the ***serialized version of `Feed` instances*** with the help of **`NotificationSerializer`** as below

```
class NotificationViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    """
    This viewset returns a notifications feed for the logged in user.
    The feed contains events for when a relevant snippet is created.
    """
    serializer_class = NotificationSerializer

    def list(self, request):
        user_id = request.user.id
        notification_feed = feed_manager.get_notification_feed(user_id)
        serializer = NotificationSerializer(notification_feed)
        serializer.is_valid() # this has no effect in your code
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: this throws error `'Feed' object is not iterable` on line `return Response(serializer.data)`

Comment: I needed to add `serializer.is_valid()` before returning to the Response. But the notifications feed is still empty. How do I make `/notifications` return an array of snippet notifications?

Comment: Is your `notification_feed` empty? Apart from that, you don't need to call **`is_valid()`** if you are passing a ***instance*** to the serializer.

Comment: Have you tried running https://github.com/morenoh149/django-rest-framework-getstream ? its all there

Comment: I didn't. Because the error you specified is more related to Django and DRF context.